# jQuery with validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

I've problem with the jQuery validation plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input:submit').button();

       $('form').validate({
        rules: {
                name: 'required',
            email: {
                required: 'true',
                email: 'true'
            },
            subject: 'required',
            message: 'required'
        },
        messages: {
            name: '<img src="images/icons/bullet_delete.png" />',
            email: '<img src="images/icons/bullet_delete.png" />',
            subject: '<img src="images/icons/bullet_delete.png" />',
            message: ''
        }
    });
});
```

The name and subject errors are shown when submit button is pressed, but the email error is shown on blur, when the emailfield loses focus. What do I've to change so that all errors are shown after the submit button is pressed?

Comment: i think it does both, does a check onblur and when submitted, you just dont see it added because its already added once you've put in a invalid email, which is what you want as they should be notified right away if something invalid.

Comment: Also one more thing - you have acception rate 0% - please mark answers to your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

> This method sets up event handlers for submit, focus, keyup, blur and
>   click to trigger validation of the entire form or individual elements.
>   Each one can be disabled, see the onxxx options (onsubmit, onfocusout,
>   onkeyup, onclick).

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:submit').button();

    $('form').validate({
        onsubmit   : true,
        onfocusout : false,
        onkeyup    : false,
        onclick    : false,

        rules: {
            name: 'required',
            email: {
                required: 'true',
                email: 'true'
            },
            subject: 'required',
            message: 'required'
        },
        messages: {
            name: '<img src="images/icons/bullet_delete.png" />',
            email: '<img src="images/icons/bullet_delete.png" />',
            subject: '<img src="images/icons/bullet_delete.png" />',
            message: ''
        }
    });
});
```